# NServiceBus handling long running process - Transaction

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nservicebus

I have a NServiceBus Handler that handles Tiff creation Events. Typically the creation of the TIFF can take 1-5 minutes. I am using NHibernatePersistence and SqlServerTransport in the bus configuration.

Whilst the Handler is creating the Tiff, the associated database bus table is locked. So any other events are effectively queued behind.

Is there a way of allowing the other Tiff events to be processed please?

Comment: Are you hosting messagehandlers for other messages in this endpoint as well? In that case, you should consider moving the long-running process to a separate endpoint specific for just creating the TIFF. Configure this endpoint with a longer transaction timeout or turn transactions off completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all database actions are part of a distributed transaction.

You are not really clear on the type of locking that you want to prevent. If this is really a table lock how did it get a table lock?

If you do not want locking then

- add indexes on the database so queries do not escalate in a table lock
- use a lower transaction isolation level
- use transactions that are not part of the distributed transaction by creating a transaction scope with requires new. This requires idempotent processing.

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/transactions#transactions-ambient-transaction-isolation-level

```
BusConfiguration busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
busConfiguration.Transactions().IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
```